# JNI - Why rt.jar System.load not working but wrapped method working?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

And here is a demo (I omit utils, They just check if exception and print message):

First try, It should work:

C++ part:

```cpp
jclass jClass_java_lang_System = env->FindClass("java/lang/System");
jmethodID jMethodID_java_lang_System_load = env->GetStaticMethodID(jClass_java_lang_System, "load", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jClass_java_lang_System, jMethodID_java_lang_System_load, library_path);
```

No exception but after that, Call a native method cause `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

Second try, Write a wrapper method:

```
public static void load(String path) {
    System.load(path);
}
```

And call it from C++

```cpp
jmethodID jMethodID_Driver_load = env->GetStaticMethodID(jClass_Driver, "load", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jClass_Driver, jMethodID_Driver_load, library_path);
checkException(env);
```

It just a wrapper for System.load and nothing else, It working fine. The native call working properly.

Then for more test but not make any sense - Use both of them:

```cpp
jclass jClass_java_lang_System = env->FindClass("java/lang/System");
jmethodID jMethodID_java_lang_System_load = env->GetStaticMethodID(jClass_java_lang_System, "load", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jClass_java_lang_System, jMethodID_java_lang_System_load, library_path);
if (!checkException(env)) std::cout << "Load by rt.jar no Exception" << std::endl;

jclass jClass_Driver = env->FindClass("Driver");
jmethodID jMethodID_Driver_load = env->GetStaticMethodID(jClass_Driver, "load", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jClass_Driver, jMethodID_Driver_load, library_path);
checkException(env); // The first UnsatisfiedLinkError print by this util

// Second UnsatisfiedLinkError print by native method call, I omit it.
```

Got this result:

```
Load by rt.jar no Exception
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library XXXXX already loaded in another classloader
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: XXXXXXX
```

That make it more confuse, The first try show load by `java.lang.System-load()` not working but in fact the library is loaded. Then throw a duplicate load exception.

And reverse the order:

```cpp
jclass jClass_Driver = env->FindClass("Driver");
jmethodID jMethodID_Driver_load = env->GetStaticMethodID(jClass_Driver, "load", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jClass_Driver, jMethodID_Driver_load, library_path);
checkException(env);

jclass jClass_java_lang_System = env->FindClass("java/lang/System");
jmethodID jMethodID_java_lang_System_load = env->GetStaticMethodID(jClass_java_lang_System, "load", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jClass_java_lang_System, jMethodID_java_lang_System_load, library_path);
if (!checkException(env)) std::cout << "Load by rt.jar no Exception" << std::endl;
```

And got this result:

```
Load by wrapper no Exception
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library XXXX already loaded in another classloader
Result is - 2468
Result is - 2468
```

Even throw a duplicate load exception, The native call working propproperly.

Question: What happen? How to solve?

Comment: What happens? Once a library is loaded, it's native methods are bound and working. A second load does nothing besides throwing `UnsatisfiedLinkError`. How to solve? Just make sure you load a native library exactly once. Don't try to load it  again if it's already there.

Comment: @user2543253 It's not talking about load twice, It's talking about why the rt.jar provied method not working but a wrappered method will.

Comment: But you say yourself, that both ways *do* work. The first call succeeds, the second doesn't. First you have this output "Load by rt.jar no Exception", and below "Load by wrapper no Exception"

Comment: @user2543253 No exception but in fact/ internal, It's not loaded.

Comment: Ah, I see. The library is in fact loaded. But the native methods are not bound. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load a native library with `System.load()` the VM will try to bind any JNI functions it finds to their Java counterparts, i.e. the class that declares the native methods. It can only do that when that class is already loaded. If you load the class afterwards you will have unbound native methods, and when you call them you get an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

To be able to call your wrapper method, you *do* load the class and therefore the VM *can* bind the native methods. To make this work with only a call to `System.load()`, make sure the VM already has the class. That said, it would probably be better to use the usual way of loading the native library from a static initializer in the class itself. `loadLibrary` will also find statically linked libraries. So if you separate the JNI functions from the rest of your code, and put them into their own library, you can statically link that and use `loadLibrary` with a simple name.